# Преобразовать вложенные структуры полученные из go-tarantool

Tags: golang, tarantool

Всем доброго дня!
Я новичок в Go и вот возникла проблема.

[image: Скрин ответа от go-tarantool CallTyped]

После вызова процедуры [CallTyped](https://github.com/tarantool/go-tarantool#custom-unpacking-and-typed-selects-and-function-calls) библиотеки [go-tarantool](https://github.com/tarantool/go-tarantool) получаю вот такую структуру данных как на изображении. Мне надо описать type struct таким образом, что бы получить доступ ко всем свойствам.

Дошёл до:

```
type ObData struct {
    D1 []map[string]interface{}
    D2 interface{}
}
```

И вместо `map[string]interface{}` я бы хотел иметь структуру, а внутри ещё и т.д.